# PHP Notice: Undefined variable: Error In PHP Script

Tags: php, undefined, error-log

I have a php script which I'm using on my newest website, and while I've never had a problem with using this same type of coding before, I'm now getting a lot of errors.  Here's the code that I'm using:

```
$articles_sql = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 20";
$articles_res = mysqli_query($con, $articles_sql);
while($articles = mysqli_fetch_assoc($articles_res)){
    $articles_id = $articles["id"];
    $articles_title = $articles["title"];
    $articles_text = $articles["text"];
    $articles_text = strip_tags($articles_text);
    $articles_text = substr($articles_text,0,140);
    $articles_added = $articles["added"];

    $articles_year = date("Y", strtotime($articles_added));
    $articles_date = date("jS F Y, g:ia", strtotime($articles_added));

    $display_random_articles .= " // ERROR FOR THIS LINE

        <div class=\"block\">
            <div class=\"blockAvatar\">
                <img class=\"blockAvatarImg\" src=\"images/articles/$articles_year/$articles_id.jpg\" />
                <div class=\"blockAvatarCover\"></div>
            </div>
            <div class=\"blockIcons blockIconPaper\"></div>
            <div class=\"blockContent blockContentNarrow\">
                <li class=\"blockDate\">$articles_date</li>
                <li><strong><a href=\"article.php?id=$articles_id\">$articles_title</a></strong></li>
                <li class=\"blockText\">$articles_text...</li>
                <li class=\"blockDate\">... <a href=\"article.php?id=$articles_id\">Read On</a> &raquo;&raquo;</li>
            </div>
            <div class=\"clearLeft\"></div>
        </div>

    ";
}
```

Now everything appears to be fine visually but I've just looked at the Error_Log and it's full of the same little errors warning of `undefined variables`:

`PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: display_random_articles in ...` On the line that I outlined above.  Does anyone know why I'm getting this error and more importantly, is there any way of getting rid of it?

Comment: Well you got a funny error message! `display_random_blogs` <> `$display_random_articles`

Comment: try to define $display_random_articles = ''.

Comment: Sorry @Rizier123, Like I said I'm getting a few errors so both `display_random_blogs` & `display_random_articles` are showing up

Comment: @anantkumarsingh, Sorry but how do I do that?

Comment: You never bothered initializating `$display_random_articles`, so when the `$display_random_articles .= ".etc..."` executes for the first time, there's no variable to concatenate with, hence your error.

Comment: Try to write it  very upside before while

Comment: I'm sorry @MarcB but I don't understand! How do I initialize?

Comment: `$d_r_a = ''` somewhere before you start the loop, basically. just give it a value. any value.

Comment: @MarcB - So why won't THIS variable get an error? I thought that the value of the `$d_r_a` was what is written after the `=`! Somewhere else in my script I have `$site_url = "http://.....com"` and this doesn't get any errors - What's different about my `$r_d_a`?

Comment: @MarcB Is it something to do with variables that have a `.` placed before the `=`?

Comment: because you're using `.=`. that's shortcut for `$x = $x . $y`. you have to ACCESS $x to concatenate it with $y, before the result can be assigned back to it. since it doesn't exist on the first loop iteration, you're effectively doing `$x = undefined . $y`.

Comment: Yeah I looked back at my Error Log and worked out that variables with a `.=` were where the errors were showing up.  I'll go back and initialize each variable above this scripting.  Cheers @MarcB